# Issues with installing Orchard & Mono

Tags: mono, content-management-system, orchardcms

I am currently running an Ubuntu Server 12.10.

I tried to install Orchard along with mono. When i try to start mono :

```
MONO_IOMAP=all xsp4
```

I get the following errors in the CLI:

```
    Handling exception type ConfigurationErrorsException
Message is No factory for host (/home/shto/sites/test/Orchard/Web.config line 13)
IsTerminating is set to True
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: No factory for host (/home/shto/sites/test/Orchard/Web.config line 13)

Server stack trace: 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigInfo.ThrowException (System.String text, System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadRemoveSection (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadConfig (System.Configuration.Configuration cfg, System.String streamName, System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.SectionGroupInfo.ReadConfig (System.Configuration.Configuration cfg, System.String streamName, System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.ReadConfigFile (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Load () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Init (IConfigSystem system, System.String configPath, System.Configuration.Configuration parent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration (System.String path, System.String site, System.String locationSubPath, System.String server, System.String userName, System.String password, Boolean fweb) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

Exception rethrown at [0]: 

  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)
  at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource webSource) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

When i installed mono i used the command: `apt-get install mono-complete`

Answer (score 0):

Orchard currently does not run in Mono.

Comment: "In order to get Orchard working you need one of the Mono versions mentioned above and a couple of patches applied to the Orchard sources.
Generic Mono changes - introduces support for Mono debugging information files (.mdb) as well as changes the top-level Web.config to make it compatible with Mono.
PostgreSQL support - introduces support for PostgreSQL and is not specific to Mono." source - http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/247340#post849907

Comment: My point is that Orchard can work/run on Mono. See another example here(dated on MAR 17TH, 2013 ): http://blog.erikd.org/2013/03/17/run-asp-dot-net-mvc4-on-ubuntu-12-dot-10/ . My final goal is to make the last version of Orchard run on linux. If you know any other way, please do tell :).

Comment: In principle, yes, it *could*, but in practice, we need an owner for this who knows Mono well enough and is motivated enough to make it work. Today, it doesn't. I never said it couldn't. We all want it to. If you want to be that person, that's fantastic. I was under the impression that you just expected it to work out of the box, hence my answer. I'm afraid I can't help much in getting you past that error. Looks like it breaks in web.config, on lines related to Razor. I'd start with a smaller test app, and try each of the config lines 1 by 1.